# Changing port with javascript window.location

Tags: javascript, menu, port

Currently a page i am editing has a JS menu. This contains items such as;

```
{
    xtype: 'tbbutton',
    text: 'Home',
    width: 60,
    handler: function() { window.location = 'index.php'; }
},
```

However due to how the server is set up i need to change port number between pages, as some are unable to handle the php used on the pages. (Trying to base on someone elses program to fit my purpose)

From what I have seen on here it suggests this should work

```
{
    xtype: 'tbbutton',
    text: 'Home',
    width: 60,
    handler: function() { window.location.port = 80; window.location = 'index.php'; }
},
```

So result i am aiming for in index.php would be on port 80 and page1.html, page2.html on port 81. User being able to jump between them with a click regardless of port. The page could be accessed on home network (with a 192. address) or Via web (with public IP) so I would prefer not to have to set the domain each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the window.location to a full URL with the port number in it:

```
window.location = "http://adomain.com:80/index.php";
```

---

If you want to use the current domain, then you can construct the URL using `window.location.hostname` to use the current host.

```
window.location = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":80/index.php";
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but as stated there is no domain it is accessed by IP and that could be public or Internal so wanted to cater for both.

Comment: @bighead85 - See the second part of my answer.  It should work with the current domain/IP whichever is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this

```
{
xtype: 'tbbutton',
text: 'Home',
width: 60,
handler: function() { window.location = 'index.php'; }
},
```

Use location.port = 80; in your index.php this will work

Use location.port = 80; Will change your current port.

Comment: That is the sort of thing i have been trying, however for some reason this isn't changing the port on the request.

Comment: Use location.port = 80; in your index.php file and use only  window.location = 'index.php'; to redirect page.

Comment: Thank you, not too sure why but still could not get this to work on my pages. (Although this is what I thought should be happening) This maybe something to do with where menu is located or something, using @jfriend00 this is working. So will stick with that, thank you for the suggestion.